# Прозрачные окна в phpstorm, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains

Здравствуйте. Есть такой баг на конкретной машине: окна в phpstorm совершенно прозрачные, контента не видно([Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xhnb.png)). Есть идеи в чем проблема и как пофиксить?

Comment: больше похоже не на «прозрачность», а на отсутствие содержимого, вызванного проблемами в работе программы, создавшей это окно. попробуйте запустить программу в эмуляторе терминала и посмотрите, пишется ли что-то в *stdout/stderr* при открытии данного окна.

Answer (score 1):

Известная проблема, к сожалению:( Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за [IDEA-110048](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110048)